When I start docker. Host SSH (And all other incoming networking) stop working

Ubuntu 22 Server
Docker installed via apt

I was trying to fix a docker container volume by moving data between volumes (Accidentally killed a container that had a non-persistent volume, so I was recovering it from the un-deleted previous volume). Upon starting the container (Which had been started previously) my SSH connection times out, as do all other networking to services hosted on the host.
If I use a virtual console and kill docker, this does not restore SSH. If I restart sshd this does not restore SSH. If I reboot, and the docker service starts, SSH dies. If I disabled docker and restart, I can SSH in again. If I then start docker, SSH dies.
lsof -i :22 shows that sshd is listening on port 22
tcpdump -i ens18 port 22 shows that when SSH'ing in there are incoming SYN but no ACK responses.
If I disable the offending container and reboot. I can SSH in again. However, if I run ANY docker commands (ie. docker ps) the SSH connection dies and cannot be re-opened.
What's going on here??
Edit: It looks like when restarting the jellyfin container the network config for it changed to the same network segment as my host, instead of the internal docker network segment. Removing this network restored all functionality. How or why this happened, I still don't know.
